# How can I achieve this type of very clean halftone effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, halftone

How can I achieve this type of very clean halftone effect  ?

[image]

Comment: Hi Clemence. Welcome to GDSE. Can you tell us what software you are using, and what you have tried, or what has failed. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I'm using photoshop. I've tried with the bitmap technique, but its not very smooth

Comment: i have trouble to achieve a result with very clean dots

Comment: Notice that the half-tone dots are square rather than round and the screen angle is 90° to make them more pronounced.

Comment: Are you sure that image was created with Photoshop and not illustrator? Crisper shapes are usually vector.

Comment: @Luciano yes maybe with illustrator like this one : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o4AZaGeHQA

Comment: Also, if you want to make it similarly "smooth" as that reference image, prep your image first before halftoning. The reference image has been blurred prior to halftoning. You may even use brush and erase tool (with really soft edges) to create/take out details.

Answer (score 7):

Click *Image > Mode > Grayscale*  (if the image is not already grayscale).

Click *Filter > Pixelate > Color Halftone*

Set the dot size you want, and set the Channel 1 value to 0. Ignore the others as they won't be used anyway.

[image]

After you have finished, you can convert the document back to RGB mode if you need to add colour elements.

Only problem with this is that it seems to create a white square grid pattern over the face. I've no idea what's causing that, so this PS filter might not be the best.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i've got much better result with your advice

Answer (score 1):

The Grayscale image has at first got levels or curves adjustment which makes the background full white and the darkest point black. Then a gaussian blur is applied to fade all sharp edges which would make the halftoning to look out crispy.

The halftoning of the grayscale image is made with Image > Mode > Bitmap > Halftone Screen > Round. Have a high output resolution to get solid looking dots.

The image is converted back to RGB (at first to grayscale from bitmap) and colorized slightly. Several coloring methods are available:

1) with Image > Adjustments > Hue&Saturation > colorize

2) by adding a colored layer with blending mode multiply.

3) with layer style "Color overlay"

Method 2 is used here

[image]

Your image is colorized with nearly or even exactly grey. It can be done also with adjusting levels.